# Looping problem Elden ring runes per level calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, calculator, calculation

This code is currently showing the total amount needed to reach the next level, but what I would like it to do is show the complete total amount so for example if you pick 50 the total amount needed from level 1 to 50. Looping through the calculation from 50 to 1 and only showing the sum of that total. and hereby I mean only showing the total amount of runes needed to reach level 50 for example, but I seem to get the entire list for each level. I, unfortunately, can't seem to find the right way to do this online, so I would try my luck here. any help is appreciated.

```
def total_runes_per_lvl(lvl):
    list = []
    for i in range(lvl):
        runes = 0.02*(lvl)**3 + 3.06*(lvl)**2 + 105.6*(lvl) - 895
        list.append(runes)
        lvl -= 1
        
        print(sum(list))
    
total_runes_per_lvl(50)

15102.68
14535.0
28514.440000000002
41950.32
54854.520000000004
67238.8
etc`
```

should only be one number: 277.571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your identation is incorrect, and you're decrementing `lvl` even though there's already an iterator on it.

```py
def total_runes_per_lvl(lvl):
    total = 9381
    for i in range(13,lvl+1):
        runes = 0.02*(i+1)**3 + 3.06*(i+1)**2 + 105.6*(i+1) - 895
        total += int(runes)
        
    print(total)
total_runes_per_lvl(16) # 15605
total_runes_per_lvl(50) # 277574
```

Edit: since the formula works accurately after level 12, I've hardcoded the value for the total of first 12 levels. The formula works as expected, though it still isn't accurate.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not quite what I am looking for, this function gives the sum of each previous total runes level not the number of runes needed to reach the next level. so the formula calculates the number of runes one needs to reach the next level. so from one to two 600 and 2 to 3 630 etc, and what I want is the outcome of that summation up until level x. the function that you have provided gives the summation of the totals up until level x. it's linear, not logarithmic. I do fully appreciate the help though.

Comment: Can you explain what `runes` is in `runes = 0.02*(lvl)**3 + 3.06*(lvl)**2 + 105.6*(lvl) - 895`?

Comment: Runes the amount of XP(runes) needed to go from one level to another. so from level one to two you need for example 600 XP(runes) and from two to three 640. So what I am looking for is the sum of those numbers up to input lvl. what your code does is sum the totals generated. Sidenote: the formula is accurate until lvl 12.  maybe a useful to look at the levelling site in the wiki(LEVEL CALCULATION IN ELDEN RING) https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Level  (the possibility does exist that i'm might being stupid, but not sure)

Comment: " from level one to two you need for example 600 XP" But the formula doesn't evaluate to 600?

Comment: Yes, it does, but the formula does some weird stuff in the first couple levels because of the - 895 correction but never mind. if you know a way to only print the last digit in the original code that would be great.

Comment: @DaLuSt the formula is slightly weird, I've edited the answer to give you the idea.

Comment: You are a true Hero, cheers, very good call to start from the minimal base lvl of 12